# I am trying to use atom as my python editor but every time I run the program I receive some weird error about PATH.

Tags: path, syntax-error, atom-editor

I am trying to use atom as my python editor but every time I run the program I receive some weird error about PATH. My code works just fine in other editors such as PyScripter but just not Atom.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled Atom multiple times but I receive the same error.

```
# shmup game
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 480
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 60

# define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# initialize pygame and create window
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shmup!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 40))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 10
        self.speedx = 0
    def update(self):
        self.speedx = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -5
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 5
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        self.rect.x += self.speedx

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 40))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -49)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(-3, 3)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top > HEIGHT + 10 or self.rect.left < -25 or 
        self.rect.right > WIDTH + 20:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -49)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 8)



all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
for i in range(8):
    m = Mob()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)
# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    # keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Update
    all_sprites.update()
    # check to see if mob hit player
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs, False)

    # Draw / render
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

and this is my error
    Unable to find command: python

```
Are you sure PATH is configured correctly?

ENV PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\ProgramData\Lenovo\ReadyApps

Error: spawn python ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using [`atom-runner`](https://atom.io/packages/atom-runner), in that case, according to a response to [issue #127](https://github.com/lsegal/atom-runner/issues/127):

> Your `PATH` needs to include at least one directory with the `python.exe` binary inside of it. My guess is that none of the directories you listed at the end have the executable in them. You should go into your `Python35` directory and look for the `python.exe` binary (usually in a `bin\` sub-directory) and use that path in your environment variable.

I also see that you don't have Atom in your `PATH` either, you should add the following directory to it:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\atom\bin
```